# React npm run deploy no me funciona

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, git

Estoy intentando subir mi primera app react a mi repositorio de hub siguiendo este [tutorial](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f). Al momento de utilizar el comando `npm run deploy` me muestra el siguiente error. [image: error consola]

Por lo que pude investigar es un problema con Git, porque tenia configurado las credenciales de mi trabajo y no las de github. Las he cambiado pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo la palabra "sudo" antes. De esta manera le estarás dando permisos.
Luego te pedirá la clave de tu computadora.

```
sudo npm run deploy
```